# Laravel WebSockets - deployment - fails to connect the websocket

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, websocket, cpanel

I am trying to deploy my laravel project with websockets built on Beyond Code's package.
My server is on AWS and i'm using WHM.

on the cPanel's terminal i'm running the line `php artisan websockets:serve` 
and i get the result `Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...`

when i'm loading the page with the websocket's connection sometimes i get the error `failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`
and sometimes i get the error `failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`

On AWS EC2's Security Groups i allowed the Custom TCP port 6001 and 6002

**Any suggestions to fix it?**

**Maybe a good deployment tutorial for Laravel WebSockets?**

I'm looking for answers all over the internet and i get nothing useful.

Comment: Is it running on wss or ws? Mine, I use docker swarm and running behind nginx proxy and behind another cloud flare proxy. Nothing broke except that I run it on WS protocol since I don't have time to setup the encryption and certificate ssl.

Comment: @CTOKoder did you make any progress and this?